# Optimizar consulta count(*)

Tags: sql-server, sql

les comento.
Actualmente estoy usando una query que me trae los totales de los registros para varias tablas, alojadas en 3 servidores diferentes. Esto lo realizo para comparar si entre los 3 servidores hay diferencias de datos para cada una de estas tablas.

La sentencia que uso es esta:

```
        SELECT GETDATE() AS Fecha_Proceso, 'Nombre_tabla' AS Nombre_tabla,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM linked_server.tabla1) AS 'Tabla1',
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM linked_server2.tabla2) AS 'tabla2',
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tabla_local) AS 'tabla_local'
        UNION
        SELECT GETDATE() AS Fecha_Proceso, 'Nombre_tabla' AS Nombre_tabla,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM linked_server.tabla1) AS 'Tabla1',
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM linked_server2.tabla2) AS 'tabla2',
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tabla_local) AS 'tabla_local'
        UNION
    etc...
```

La tabla quedaria algo asi:

```
    | Fecha_proceso | Nombre_tabla | Servidor1 | Servidor2 | Servidor_local |
    |---------------|--------------|-----------|-----------|----------------|
    | Fecha_actual1 | Nombre1      | 1234      | 1234      | 1234           |
    | Fecha_actual2 | Nombre2      | 4567      | 4567      | 4567           |

etc...
```

Habra algun metodo mas eficiente en el que pueda realizarlo, ya que son mas de 60 tablas que hay que comparar entre 3 servidores (1 servidor local, dos servidores linkeados). Y otro detalle, no son todas las tablas de una base de datos, solo algunas las que hay que comparar.

Espero me puedan ayudar y de antemano, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí dejo un código que puede servir. El único inconveniente es que lee los datos de una tabla de sistema y los permisos pueden ser un problema.

```
WITH TablasLocales AS(
    SELECT t.name nombre_tabla, SUM(s.row_count) AS Conteo
    FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats s
    JOIN sys.tables t ON s.object_id = t.object_id
    WHERE index_id <= 1 --Clustered index or heap
    AND t.name IN('Tu', 'lista', 'de', 'tablas')
    GROUP BY t.name
),
TablasLinkedServer1 AS(
    SELECT t.name nombre_tabla, SUM(s.row_count) AS Conteo
    FROM LinkedServer1.BaseDeDatos.sys.dm_db_partition_stats s
    JOIN LinkedServer1.BaseDeDatos.sys.tables t ON s.object_id = t.object_id
    WHERE index_id <= 1 --Clustered index or heap
    AND t.name IN('Tu', 'lista', 'de', 'tablas')
    GROUP BY t.name
),
TablasLinkedServer2 AS(
    SELECT t.name nombre_tabla, SUM(s.row_count) AS Conteo
    FROM LinkedServer2.BaseDeDatos.sys.dm_db_partition_stats s
    JOIN LinkedServer2.BaseDeDatos.sys.tables t ON s.object_id = t.object_id
    WHERE index_id <= 1 --Clustered index or heap
    AND t.name IN('Tu', 'lista', 'de', 'tablas')
    GROUP BY t.name
)
SELECT GETDATE() AS fecha_proceso,
    tl.nombre_tabla,
    tls1.Conteo AS Servidor1,
    tls2.Conteo AS Servidor2,
    tl.Conteo AS Servidor_local
FROM TablasLocales tl
JOIN TablasLinkedServer1 tls1 ON tl.nombre_tabla = tls1.nombre_tabla
JOIN TablasLinkedServer2 tls2 ON tl.nombre_tabla = tls2.nombre_tabla;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias estimado! Te pasaste!!! Ahora, el problema que me queda es buscar los datos del sistema para un servidor antiguo IBM de donde extraemos los datos principales, pero en si me funciono perfecto, se agradece un monton.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que esto solo sirve en SQL Server de la versión 2005 en adelante. No sé a que te refieras con "un servidor antiguo IBM".

Comment: Me refiero a un servidor AS400, pero ya solucione mi problema a ello, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Para mas de 50 tablas y en diferentes servidores yo mejor crearía una tabla en la cual los campos fueran el resultado de tu query.

```
| Field          | Type         | Null | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+--------------+------+---------+----------------+
| ID             | Int(15)      | NO   | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Nombre_Tabla   | varchar(25)  | NO   | NULL    |                |
| Servidor1      | varchar(25)  | NO   | NULL    |                |
| Servidor2      | varchar(25)  | NO   | NULL    |                |
| Servidor_Local | varchar(25)  | NO   | NULL    |                |
```

Despues crearia un trigger en cada tabla, en cada servidor que contara y actualizara el campo correspondiente.

```
CREATE TRIGGER BaseDeDatos.Update_Nombre_Tabla
ON BaseDeDatos.Nombre_Tabla
AFTER INSERT, DELETE
AS
DECLARE @Contar int
SELECT @Contar = COUNT(*) FROM Nombre_Tabla
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE BaseDeDatos.Tabla_Redundancia(Servidor1 = @contar)
END
```

Asi solo consultas esta tabla y no todas las tablas en diferentes servidores.

Es solo una idea..

Igual y contar solo los indices en lugar de todos los campos ayudaria al rendimiento

Comment: y si agregas con código como harías lo que describes?

Comment: Hola @anonimo, no sé si a eso te referias...

Comment: Esto sólo aumentaría la carga de la base de datos. Además, esta información ya está disponible en las tablas de sistema. Si el acceso a las tablas del sistema es un problema, se puede generar una tabla adicional o un procedimiento almacenado que provea los resultados de forma segura.